# OCIEnvCreate failed with return code -1 but error message text was not available.

Tags: asp.net, oracle, iis-7

I have an asp.net application that connects to a remote oracle database. When I have the application configured in iis7 as it's own separate application, everything works fine. Since I would like the application to run off of the same port (80) as the default website in iis, I have configured the application by right clicking "Default Web Site" in iis7 and clicking add application, then I select the path to where my application is. I should be able to connect by going to "localhost/*applicationName*", but I am getting the following error:

OCIEnvCreate failed with return code -1 but error message text was not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to connect to an Oracle database you receive the following error: "OCIEnvCreate failed with return code -1 but error message text was not available"

The causes:

1) You are using an unsupported version of the Oracle Client (older than 11.2) on Windows 7.

2) DLLs from a previous installation of Oracle Client have been left on the system, causing a conflict.

The solutions:

1) Install a supported version of the Oracle Client.

2) Perform a search for "OCI.DLL" on the local machine. If you find any instances of this file in any location other than your ORACLE_HOME rename or delete it. If in doubt, uninstall the Oracle Client, then perform the search again. Anything that is leftover is the culprit.

Comment: I found one more solution :)

I've client, who installed 11.x and 12.x side by side (in Windows-7). I found that, ORACLE_HOME was not registered properly for 12.x client. I just updated proper entry in Environment for "12.x ORALCE_HOME". 

And its working fine. I think this will be better instead of removing client.